# Glass Facade Load on edge of slab?

Tags: structures, glass

How do i calculate the load of a glass facade and is it placed uniformly on the edge of the slab or should i place a point load on each edge of the panel of the facade? 
And Can anyone give me a link on an example on how to calculate the load and how to place it.
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the distributed load is trivial to determine: it is equal to the linear weight of the glass. The linear weight is itself equal to the product of the thickness, height and specific weight of the glass (depends on the type of glass, usually between 24-28 kN/m<sup>3</sup>).

How this load should be placed, however, depends on how the glass is mounted on the structure. Does it rest on a support structure directly on the slab? In this case, apply it as a uniformly distributed load. If, however, it is actually supported by vertical structures which themselves rest on1 the slab, then the load should be concentrated at the supports. In this case, the value of the concentrated force at each support is equal to the distributed load times half of the span between supports (the other half is handled by the other support).